# 二次配列をfor-in構文を使用して一次配列にし、処理したい

Tags: swift, swiftui

現在、二次配列に入った式を `for-in` 構文で一次配列にして処理したいと思っているのですが、処理しようとすると、

> Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with function builder 'ViewBuilder'

といったErrorが `for-in` 構文で発生してしまい、うまく処理できません。どのように対応すれば良いでしょうか。

**コード（サンプル）**

```
import SwiftUI

struct Author: Identifiable {
  var id: Int
  var name: String
}

struct sample: View {
    var something : [[Author]] = [[Author(id: 1, name: "Hanako"), Author(id: 2, name: "Hiroshi")],[Author(id:3, name: "Takashi")]]

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            for one in something {  ←ここでError発生
                for one in some {　　　　　
                    Text("\(one.name)")
                }
　　　　　　　　　　Divider()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。おかげさまで解決しました！

Answer (score 1):

`VStack`などに渡されるクロージャ引数は`@ViewBuilder`と呼ばれる特殊なもので、その中には通常のfor文を書くことはできません。

単純な繰り返しを表現する場合には、`ForEach`構造体を使います。

例えばこんなふうに書けるでしょう。

```
struct Sample: View {
    var something : [[Author]] = [[Author(id: 1, name: "Hanako"), Author(id: 2, name: "Hiroshi")],[Author(id:3, name: "Takashi")]]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(something.indices) {index in
                ForEach(self.something[index]) {one in
                    Text("\(one.name)")
                }
                Divider()
            }
        }
    }
}
```